# Accessing input names with array pattern jQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to access, via jQuery, the following input names in order to change their state properties based on a group of possible options. The markup is the following:

```
<input name="extra[00]" id="extra[00]" type="text" class="optional-field extra " value="" disabled="disabled">
<input name="extra[01]" id="extra[01]" type="text" class="optional-field extra " value="" disabled="disabled">
<input name="extra[02]" id="extra[02]" type="text" class="optional-field extra " value="" disabled="disabled">
<input name="extra[20]" id="extra[20]" type="text" class="optional-field extra " value="" disabled="disabled">
<input name="extra[21]" id="extra[21]" type="text" class="optional-field extra " value="" disabled="disabled">
<input name="extra[30]" id="extra[30]" type="text" class="optional-field extra " value="" disabled="disabled">
```

The first digit in name="extra[XX]" states a group and that's why it may repeat, while the second sets the order. I was trying this, but can't find a way to get the second possible element:

```
var id = jQuery(this).val(); // Changes from a drop-down
var extra = jQuery('input[name="extra[' + id + ']"]');
```

Is it possible to count how many "extra" elements are in the DOM starting, for instance by the id=2 (`jQuery('input[name="extra[2*]"]')`) ?

Thank in advance for any help.

Comment: I would think about changing your design here. You could use a combination of `class` and `data` attributes instead and then forget about the confusing names and ids.

Comment: Can't, because these might change depending on several factors, from having none, to more than one and even the id's being different. The html markup is populated from the database and I can't tell what might come from there, so I need to do this after they are rendered. Thanks anyway for the tip Cory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
$('input[name^="extra\\[2"]').length
```

Need to escape the **[** with **\\**

This will give you the length of input elements that start with `name="extra[2"`

**^** is the `attribute starts with selector`.

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/qp4PQ/)**

Comment: That's the one! Great help everyone. This was really helpful.

Comment: @Mario .. Glad to have helped :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `$("#container input[name=^extra]");` to select all the elements that begins with `extra`. Then just count the number of elements in that list. :)